# iframe set src value from a php file without show file path in source code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, iframe, pdf.js

In my Laravel project I'm using PDF.JS for display some PDF documents.
I'm trying to hide the pdf path passing a php file in the src field of iframe.

In my view:

```
<iframe id="reader" src="http://server.dev/Wrapper.php"></iframe>
```

In my Wrapper.php:

```
<?php
//here I will call some methods to compose right uri
echo "http://server.dev/libs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://server.dev/repository/ex.pdf";
?>
```

It doesn't work, It display the url inside the body tag of iframe:

```
<iframe id="reader" src="http://server.dev/Wrapper.php">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            http://server.dev/libs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://server.dev/repository/ex.pdf
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

It's possible to display the pdf file without show the pdf path directly in the source code?

Thanks

Comment: You may get away with simply using `readfile()` on your URL, and you'll also need the appropriate content type headers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your Wrapper.php file

```
  header("Content-type: application/pdf");
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
  ob_end_flush();
  @readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

Comment: YES! I spent 2h to try to fix that! Now it works like a charm, thank you very much! In my view I put `<iframe id="reader" src="/libs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://server.dev/Wrapper.php">` and in the wrapper your snippet code.

Comment: Glad it worked! But be careful to secure the input data